# Java to MySql Connection on Linux

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I googled this topic but I have yet to find the answer. I am on AWS Amazon instance running Java trying to run simple java to mysql database. I can access db fine through the mysql command. The error is driving me insane.

Note I am running under /development which happens to have the jar file.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-232 development]$ ls
cProgram.c  Java2MySql.class  Java2MySql.java  mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar 

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-232 development]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-232 development]$ java -cp /home/ec2-user/development/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar Java2MySql.java

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-232 development]$ java Java2MySql
Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?
MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smarteregsBlog
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at Java2MySql.main(Java2MySql.java:21)
Closing connection
```

Java2MySql.java

```
public class Java2MySql
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myBlog";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String userName = "sam";
  String password = "Yoo!";
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
       Class.forName(driver);
     }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
    }

      System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

   try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
       try {
            System.out.println("Closing connection");
            conn.close();
          } catch (Throwable ignore){}

     }
 }
```

Comment: Are u sure the mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar is present under home/ec2-user/development ?

Comment: check if mysqlconnector jar file is available under your class path

Comment: Unless I am blind, [ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-232 development]$ ls
Java2MySql.class  Java2MySql.java  mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar

Comment: Why not use single `try..catch` block, and `printStackTrace()` of exception caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you provide the jar only at compile time and not providing the jar class path when you try to execute the code:

```
javac -cp /home/ec2-user/development/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar Java2MySql.java
```

I assume it to be a typo `javac` and not `java`

You need to provide the jar path when executing the code as well. So change this

```
java Java2MySql
```

to

```
java -cp .:/home/ec2-user/development/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar Java2MySql
```

**Note:** mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar is only required at runtime in your case because you are loading the class dynamically.

Comment: Great, Works, How can I fix this so I don't have to put in, Assuming the variables I showed in my original post?

Comment: @ironman2012 Fix what? Not having to provide the classpath? In that case you need to package it in a jar which has a `Class-Path` entry in its manifest.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, No I meant How to not specify the class path explicitly everytime I compile and run the executable?

Answer (score 0):

Well while compiling the class you don't need to specify the jar in this case so simple this should do the job

```
javac Java2MySql.java
```

Change this

```
java -cp /home/ec2-user/development/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar Java2MySql.java
```

to

```
java -cp .:pathOfTheDriverJar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar Java2MySql
```

Comment: well if you know to run a class through terminal i think we never give `.java` while executing the class

Comment: Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

Comment: I don't understand how can some people simple down vote without analyzing things

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mysql connector jar is located in your classpath. Copying it in same folder as your class file wont work.
Or you can simply copy it to lib folder of your jdk.